# Cannot access CreateBlobOptions() for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: php, azure, format, blob, azure-storage

I am currently trying to use the following php code for Azure Blob storage to modify the format of the files that I upload:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateBlobOptions;
$options = new CreateBlobOptions();
$options->setBlobContentType("image/jpeg");
```

I followed the documentation to include the Azure libraries (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs).

Yet, whenever I run my code the following error is thrown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateBlobOptions' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pano_azure/upload.php:15
```

When I look into my files I cant see the folders "\Blob\Models\" in the "WindowsAzure" folder either.

Has anybody encountered similar problems?

Thanks

Comment: can you check if the namespaces are correct. Azure has moved away from windowsazure names. when I searched github https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php I found  "use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateBlobOptions;"

Comment: Great that worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: good that it helped.